# why “Segoe UI Light” font does not render in FireFox 13.0

Tags: css, fonts

In a website, i am using "Segoe UI Light" font which does not render properly in FireFox 13.0, while it does in IE9.

i did changes in css as below

```
    font-family: Segoe UI;
    font-weight: lighter;
```

but it doesn't works for me.

so please provide a solution for this.

Answer (score 5):

Use just

```
font-family: Segoe UI Light;
```

without `font-weight`. What you are doing now is correct in principle, but Firefox, Chrome, etc., are not able to select and use the Segoe UI Light typeface properly.

Answer (score 2):

The below code worked for me and compatible with all browsers

```
 font-family: "Segoe UI Light","Segoe UI";
 font-weight: 300;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to quote the family name:

```
font-family: "Segoe UI";
font-weight: lighter;
```

Comment: Not relevant. Does not affect the situation at all.

Comment: It does give you a lighter version of Segoe UI in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I captured the css from microsoft official website, these two line should work well.
Put it into body

```
body {
    font-family: "wf_SegoeUILight","wf_SegoeUI","Segoe UI Light","Segoe WP Light","Segoe UI","Segoe","Segoe WP","Tahoma","Verdana","Arial","sans-serif";
    font-weight: 300;
}
```